# PDF java tracker

Tags: java, pdf, acrobat, form-fields

I am looking to create some sort of tracker that will allow me to see how many times a document is opened.

Is it possible to create a form field within a pdf that will download a file from a web server once it is opened?

Comment: Similar question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18029/how-to-track-opens-and-pageviews-in-pdfs

Answer (score 0):

The Acrobat Javascript Scripting specification enlists various document (doc) events. One of them is "Doc/Open". This event is fired whenever a document is opened. [Here](http://www.planetpdf.com/planetpdf/pdfs/ppjs_eventexamples.pdf) is a sample pdf file that implements the standard events, which should give you a hint of possibilities.

This [article](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=working_with_events_in_acrobat&gid=6823) explains the concept in detail.